# USB is not recognized by device manager but seen by vender's software

Tags: usb-device

I am trying to acquire data in real time from a sensor mounted on an evaluation board. This evaluation board has a software, when I connect the USB to PC, it automatically recognizes the USB and it sees the device. My problem is I would like to acquire data from this sensor by MATLAB and I need to see the port or com, but device manager doesn't show anything. How can I check my USB connection in device manager?

Comment: Sounds like a HID device. Doesn't need specific drivers to work, but does need special software to interact with it.

Comment: In that case, I can't have a real time data acquisition by MATLAB, right?

Comment: You would need to write some software to talk whatever protocol the device talks and send the data to matlab.

Answer (score 1):

"View devices by connection" can make it easier to find a device - it'll be below one of the USB root hubs.

However, USB devices don't have to define a COM port. So it might not be possible to access it without the manufacturer's software.